# Определить максимум функции быстрее чем за O(n^2)

Tags: java, алгоритм

Не знаю как нормально оптимизировать алгоритм O(n^2):

```
 public static long kodyara(long[] arr,long max)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

         for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
         {
             long val = arr[i] * (j+1) + arr[j] * (1 + i);
             max = Math.max(val, max);
         }
     }
  return max;
 }
```

Дайте совет

**Условие задачи** (https://algotester.com/en/ArchiveProblem/Display/40366)

Даны:

- целочисленный массив A размерности N (1 < N < 100000, 1 < A[i] < 1000)
- функция `f(i,j) = A[i] * j + A[j] * i`

Нужно найти максимальное значение функции.

**Примеры:**

5 - N

100 1 1 1 1

Max - 501

Ещё пример:

1 - N

1

Max - 2

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91762/discussion-on-question-by-kekw1x-------on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ограничение на значение элементов массива (1 < A[i] < 1000) сильно упрощает задачу:

### Условие

Как уже написал @pavel число может оказаться в максимальной паре только если после него в последовательности нет бо́льших чисел.

Это легко доказать: если для `i` и `j` верно, что `i<j` и `a[i]<=a[j]`, то для любого значения `x` будет верно, что `a[x]*i + x*a[i] < a[x]*j + x*a[j]`.

Следовательно, если число не является максимумом в своем суффиксе (подмассив от числа до конца массива), его можно не рассматривать как кандидата на выбор.

### Отбор

Соответственно, предлагается подход: идти по массиву с конца, обновляя максимум и запоминая элементы на которых максимум обновляется. Максимум функции всегда достигается на паре из этих элементов.

Примеры:

```
Для массива:
позиция:  1   2 3 4 5
значение: 100 1 1 1 1
будут отобраны элементы
позиция:  1         5
значение: 100       1
Остальные не имеет смысла рассматривать, т.к. справа от них в массиве встречается равное им значение.

Для массива:
позиция:  1 2 3 4 5
значение: 5 1 4 1 2
будут отобраны элементы
позиция:  1   3   5
значение: 5   4   2
```

Получим строго убывающую подпоследовательность максимальных элементов в суффиксах массива. Т.к. элементы массива могут принимать одно из 1000 значений и ни один не равен другому, то и длина массива [не будет превышать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) 1000.

После отбора имеем массив `index` длины L (L < 1000), где `index[i]` — позиция элемента в оригинальном массиве (до отбора). По позиции, через `a` можно получить значение

### Расчет

Теперь нужно просто решить задачу для полученного подмассива, а именно найти такую пару `i` и `j`, для которой `index[i]*value[j] + index[j]*value[i]`.

Это уже можно будет сделать двойным циклом проверив все возможные пары элементов. Для этого потребуется L^2/2 операций.

Те же примеры:

```
1. Для массива:
       100 1 1 1 1
отобраны элементы
index: 1         5
value: 100       1
Проверяем все возможные сочетания для L = 2:
i = 0, j = 0: index[0]*value[0]+index[0]*value[0] = 1*100 + 1*100 = 200
i = 0, j = 1: index[0]*value[1]+index[1]*value[0] = 1*1   + 100*5 = 501
i = 1, j = 1: index[1]*value[1]+index[1]*value[1] = 5*1   + 5*1   = 10
Ответ: f(1, 5) = 501

2. 
a:     5 1 4 1 2
index: 1   3   5
value: 5   4   2
Все возможные пары:
i = 0, j = 0: index[0]*value[0]+index[0]*value[0] = 1*5+1*5 = 10
i = 0, j = 1: index[0]*value[1]+index[1]*value[0] = 1*4+3*5 = 19
i = 0, j = 2: index[0]*value[2]+index[2]*value[0] = 1*2+5*5 = 27
i = 1, j = 1: index[1]*value[1]+index[1]*value[1] = 3*4+3*4 = 24
i = 1, j = 2: index[1]*value[2]+index[2]*value[1] = 3*2+5*4 = 26
i = 2, j = 2: index[2]*value[2]+index[2]*value[2] = 5*2+5*2 = 20
Ответ: f(1, 5) = 27
```

### Псевдокод

```
int n = a.length;

//Текущий максимум
int max = -1;
//Индексы отобранных элементов
//выделено n ячеек с «запасом» (можно 1000)
int[] index = new int[n];
//их количество
int l = 0;
//идем с конца
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (a[i] > max) {
        //записываем максимум
        max = a[i];
        //и индекс
        index[l++] = i;
    }
}

//рассчитываем значения функции для отобранных элементов
int result = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < l; j++) {
        int f = (index[i] + 1) * a[index[j]] + (index[j] + 1) * a[index[i]];
        result = max(result, f);
    }
}
return result;
```

### Сложность

Т.о. алгоритм сработает за O(N + L^2), где , где L — длина подпоследовательности максимальных элементов суффиксов массива.

Решение кое-как проходит только за счет сильного ограничения на `A[i]`. Возможно, имеется универсальный подход с использованием рекуррентных соотношений либо структур данных.

Comment: блин. люблю когда условие обрезают)

Comment: *Алгоритм сработает за O(N + MAX^2)* — т.е. те же O(n^2) в худшем случае? Не до конца понял...

Comment: @АндрейNOP На MAX другое ограничение (1 < N < **1000000**, 1 < A[i] < **1000**)

Comment: Ок, значит худший вариант у нас наступает при MAX > N, при этом ваш алгоритм будет работать медленнее чем у автора?

Comment: Хотя, скорее, в вашем случае алгоритм работает за O(M^2), где M=MIN(N, MAX(A)). Ну да, наверное это непринципиально, т. к. получаем в любом случае число операций не более C*10^6, против C*10^10 в худшем случае у ТС

Comment: @АндрейNOP Совершенно верно, при MAX>N алгоритм будет работать хуже чем у автора. Если быть точным, то сложность моего алгоритма O(N + L^2), где L — длина наибольшей строго убывающей подпоследовательности. И да для целых чисел L = MIN(N, MAX(A)-MIN(A)+1). Если длина диапазона допустимых значений A превысит N, то L=N.

Comment: @defaultlocale а вы сортировали массив?

Comment: @Kekw1x нет, это не нужно. Отобрать убывающую подпоследовательность можно одним проходом с конца. Ее сортировать не нужно, т.к. она уже упорядочена.

Comment: @defaultlocale не могу понять одного, я недавно только начал програмировать,вопрос очень глуп наверное,но зачем записывать максимум и записывать макс. индексы если это одно и тоже.И еще не очень понял реализацию,я спросил несколько одногрупников,они тоже не доконца понимают,тоесть в теории она понятна,но в самой реализации очень сложно понять,если у вас есть время,можете немного подробнее расказать об своем решении задачи...

Comment: @Kekw1x По сути к перебору, который у Вас не проходил по скорости нужно добавить один шаг отбора. Добавил примеров и объяснений. Надеюсь, станет понятнее.

Comment: @defaultlocale вижу,спасибо,сейчас попробую реализовать

Comment: @defaultlocale еще 1 вопрос,а как можно сохранить индексы макс елементов? Я просто не знаю как это зделать,я брал через arraylist елементы которые повторяються и удалял их через 2 цикла в методе, но индексы под которыми эти елементы без понятия как сохранить,потому что на масив я не могу выделить динамическую память в джаве,а хеш мапу я не знаю как использовать...

Comment: @defaultlocale могу прикрепить код,если нужно

Comment: @Kekw1x объявите массив длины n (сразу с «запасом») и создайте переменную-счетчик, которая будет отслеживать кол-во индексов.

Comment: @Kekw1x Впрочем, если добавлять индексы в `ArrayList` то тоже должно пройти. Просто с `ArrayList` есть дополнительные расходы на упаковку/распаковку примитивов в объекты.

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо за все,зделал...

Comment: @Kekw1x Поздравляю :)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ был изменён.

Пусть мы зафиксировали `i`. Рассмотрим оптимальное j.

```
arr[i] * (j+1) + arr[j] * (1 + i) -> max.
```

Или (помним, i - константа).

```
(arr[i]/(i+1)) * (j+1) + arr[j] -> max
```

Делить на (j+1) нельзя (тогда изменится инвариант максимума).

Если `i < i1` и `a[i] < a[i1]` то элемент `i` нас вообще не интересует. Таким образом можно считать что `a[i] > a[i+1]`.

Вычислим `S[j]` для максимального элемента. (который первый из нас интересующих).

Что произойдёт при переходе от `i` к `i+1`:
Уменьшится множитель  `arr[i]/(i+1)` (arr[i+1] - меньше, i+1 - больше).

По факту S[i+1,j] = S[i,j] - j* [разность множителей].

И нам нужно поддерживать максимум. 
Для этой цели можно использовать любое дерево с интервальной модификацией. В частности дерево отрезков (можно и Фенвика, но там сложнее писать будет).

Сложность O(N log N). Память O(N) в случе дерева фенвика и O( N log N) при дереве отрезков.

P.S. желательно обойтись без дробных операций.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы поподробнее объяснить почему 0-й элемент максимален? И какая в итоге получилась сложность?

Comment: @defaultlocale самая первая строка. По факту тут можно сразу `j` максимальный элемент выбирать. Но тогда формулы не такие прозрачные. Сложность линейная

Comment: @defaultlocale мне кажется в явно олимпиадной задаче не очень хорошо давать исчерпывающий ответ)

Comment: Ну в этом есть свой резон :) Я ответа не понял, но может автору поможет.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо,постараюсь зделать то что вы написали

Comment: Формулу с `(A[j] - A[k])/(k-j)` я тоже получил, и представлял, что нужно использовать выборку по убыванию. Но следующий шаг с выбором опорного элемента не осилил -  что из неё взять?  И сейчас не вижу, почему нулевой?

Comment: @MBo ну нулевой примерно по той причине по которой при поиске обычного минимума инициализируют нулевым. А что взять - тут есть критерий. Левая часть константа, правая зависит только от `k` и не зависит от `i` значит можно найти её значение 1 раз, найти максимум и использовать потом.

Comment: @pavel немного не понимаю как правильно по вашему ответ разбить на 2 цикла,про "i"  я понял что нужно сортировать по спадной и брать первый елемент.Немогли бы вы немного больше рассказать об вашем способе или показать код если есть время.

Comment: Все-таки не могли бы Вы разобрать работу алгоритма на простом примере (`[6, 5, 3]` и/или `[6, 5, 1]`) а то даже идею сложно понять.

Comment: @defaultlocale окей. Сравниваем 6-5/1 = 5 и 6-3/2=3/2 второе меньше (и это больше 0, значит лучше первого). Значит в пару лучше пихать третий а не второй или первый элемент. Теперь выбираем i. Можно обычный цикл используя в качестве j третий элемент. Получим 6*3+3*1 5*3+3*2 3*3+3*3 из этого (21, 21, 18) можно взять 1 или 2 всё равно. Во втором примере тоже самое. 6*5/1=5 6-1/2=5/2 лучше третий элемент. 6*3+1*1 5*3+1*2 1*3 + 3*1 - лучше первый.

Comment: @pavel спасибо, но во втором случае максимум разве не `f(2,2) = 2*5 + 2*5  = 20` ?

Comment: @pavel разобрался в арифметке и, кажется, на этих примерах все сходится. Но т.к. до меня в последнее время туго доходит, то не могли бы Вы пояснить почему не работает на примере: `[19, 15, 6]`? Смотрите: 1) `(19-15)/1 =  4, (19-6)/2 = 6.5` значит выбираем второй элемент `j = 2`. 2) перебираем i: `19*2 + 15*1 = 53, 15*2+15*2 = 60, 15*3 + 6*2 = 57` и ответ должен быть 60. Но если взять первый и третий элемент, то получится `19*3 + 6*1 = 63`. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо. я понял что не так. сейчас подумаю. нельзя было делить на k при нахождении максимума.

Comment: @defaultlocale исправил.

Comment: @pavel Стало лучше, +1. Тоже думал о структуре данных. Только не получилось придумать алгоритм для Фенвика, значения меняются неравномерно по интервалу.

Comment: @defaultlocale я ничего лучше несогласованных деревьев придумать не смог. Вполне возможно, что есть красивое решение.

Comment: @pavel Как выяснилось, из-за низкого ограничения на значения массива проходит глупый трюк.

Comment: Я объявил конкурс за «чистое» решение задачи. Буду благодарен если Вы найдете время чтобы подробно объяснить подход с деревьями.